# Bootstrap 3 ignoring column widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The start of my table is as follows, however, the column widths are anything but what I am trying to specify. Any ideas?

If I add the following, all columns are distributed evenly rather have the width I am trying to specify

```
table {
table-layout: fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

CODE

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" class="info" style="width:800px !important;"></th>
                        <th colspan="18" class="text-center success" style="border-bottom:1px black solid !important; width: 1800px !important;">Actuals</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2" class="info" style="width:100px !important;"></th>
                        <th rowspan="2" class="info" style="width:100px !important;">Measure Type</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" class="info border-right" style="width:600px !important;">Measure</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">October 18</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">November 18</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">December 18</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">January 19</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">February 19</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="success border-right border-bottom" style="width:300px !important;">March 19</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Target</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">Actual</th>
                        <th class="border-bottom border-right" style="width:100px !important;">RAG Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Comment: Setting a width on the table itself works....

Comment: you have no elasticity there - you need some columns where you dont set the width